# Can assembly directives corrupt my Ubuntu?

Tags: ram, programming

I want to start learning assembly language, and read some stuff about it.
From a first impression, it seems like the assembler pretty much gives you freedom to do whatever you want with your registers, including full freedom to access and overrun RAM memory as you wish.

Now, to my best understanding, the Windows OS will prevent any unauthorized memory access, but will Ubuntu also prevent me from screwing up?

If not, how can I practice assembly safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot corrupt your Linux system this way. If your programme tries to access a memory page it doesn't have access to, Linux will raise a [Segmentation Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Segmentation_fault_and_access_violation) exception. Your programme will receive back a SIGSEGV signal and execution is immediately halted.

Comment: In fact all modern operating systems prevent user processes from tampering with the memory of other processes or the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to write your assembler code embedded in a c program. C is a low enough level language to use the host system's asm instruction set.

The compiler will spot any obvious problems.